# Git and PowerShell and German umlauts

Tags: git, powershell, utf-8, msysgit

I've been struggling with trying to teach `msysgit` how to deal with German umlauts (ä ö ü) in e.g. commit comments. No luck .....

So I thought I might try to use PowerShell and its git integration instead (PoshGit). But again - no luck:

```
D:\temp\test [ +12 ~0 -0 !]> git add --all

D:\temp\test [ +12 ~0 -0]> git commit -m "Einige Dateien hinzugefügt"
  Warning: commit message does not conform to UTF-8.
  You may want to amend it after fixing the message, or set the config
  variable i18n.commitencoding to the encoding your project uses.
  [master (root-commit) 085b7d6] Einige Dateien hinzugef?gt
     12 files changed, 3320 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

*("Einige Dateien hinzugefügt" = some files added)*

Interesting - I could have **sworn** that the German umlauts are part of the UTF-8 standard..... hmm......

And sure enough:

```
D:\temp\test [master]> git log

  085b7d6 (HEAD, master) Einige Dateien hinzugef<FC>gt [Marc Scheuner] [4 seconds ago]
```

No banana :-(

**WHAT ON EARTH** do I have to do to get either `msysgit` (the "Git bash") or PowerShell to cooperate with Git on the commit comments? I'm not even asking for supporting file names with Umlauts... just the comments (pure text) for now.....

Also: putting this

```
[i18n]
commitencoding = ISO-8859-1
logoutputencoding = ISO-8859-1
```

into my `.gitconfig` also doesn't seem to have **any effect** on my commit comments and `git log` .... :-(

Any ideas? Thoughts? Pointers??

Comment: Why don't you use an editor to write your commit messages instead of passing them on the commandline? Or just do it like me and use english commit messages :p

Comment: @ThiefMaster: we have a policy to use German comments, and quite frankly, I'm glad - those "Engrish" comments would be horrible.....

Comment: I hope for you you don't also have to use german variable/function names ;) - buzt anyway, I'd simply omit the `-m "..."` and let git launch an editor.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I tried using an editor for my commit comments - no change, if I enter any umlauts, both the "normal" as well as the Unicode versions complain about the commit message not conforming to utf-8 (WTF!?!?!) and `git log` will show ugly hieroglyphs instead of my umlauts.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an unofficial installer for the experimental [Unicode version of msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?q=unicode) which you might want to give a try. Feedback to that installer is appreciated on the msysgit mailing list.

Comment: Looks interesting - but unfortunately, doesn't solve my problem - with this build, I cannot even enter any umlauts - the keys on the keyboard just simply don't work :-(

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem (I'm from Sweden). Seems that if you use Git Extensions and commit through that the umlaut characters are fine. I use:

```
 [i18n]
 commitencoding = windows-1252
 logoutputencoding = Windows-1252
 filesEncoding = Windows-1252
```

Would love a solution to the powershell/command line problem though.

Answer (score 1):

There known quirks and issues with MSysGit and unicode as well as simple casing. Instead of struggling with this, if I were in your shoes, I would use VritualBox with a small Linux server image (no need for desktop), and use a shared directory between host and guest OSes. This way you can use Git in Linux but develop on Windows. Open a terminal to remote to the server and you can alt+TAB to the window just like you would with MSysGit.

Comment: I think Cygwin's git plays nice and is a little less heavy than an entire vm dedicated to just source control

Comment: VMs are very light in this day and age of cpu and ram. Don't discount it. Cygwin brings a whole new set of problems. might as well bite the bullet and go with a vm.

Comment: As of today, you could also use Windows 10's Ubuntu Bash, so you don't need a VM. I actually don't use git this way, but CVS (don't ask), which doesn't work correctly on my Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with git using command line via PUTTY. 
My solution was: **Change the PUTTY-configuration for the character-set** as described here: http://thegreyblog.blogspot.de/2009/08/configuring-putty-to-use-utf-8.html

After I changed the character-set in the config of PUTTY to UTF-8 the error disappeared.

**BTW:** Like Miklos Krivan wrote in his anwer: Other people had this problem also because their username was with umlauts in .gitconfig.

Answer (score 0):

Check your encoding charset of your $HOME/.gitconfig (in Linux) or %USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig (in Windows) file which contains something like:

```
[user]
  name = Your Name
...
```

I think in your case this file is encoded with ISO-8859-1 (Your Name contains not only ASCII characters) but your project setup is for UTF-8.

I had the same situation yesterday and changing the charset of the .gitconfig file to UTF-8 solved the problem.